# Validation of viewstate MAC failed due to form action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, forms

My question is, is there a different way besides form actions to post to other pages via the client side?

I am sure the viewstate MAC error is happening because setting enableEventValidation="false" is no longer valid in web.config and I am using form actions. I have the form action attribute set in many pages and have previously posted to pages by changing this action attribute dynamically on the client side. When posting to another page via form actions, the viewstate will definitely be different.

I cannot use the recommended PostBackUrl attribute because I want to set the action attribute dynamically on the client side. PostBackUrl renders when the page loads. I also do not want to use Server.Transfer because I want the URL to change.

I am not using a web farm, and changing the validation key did not work either. This error is due to the form actions.